# Anyone can recommend a free and easy-to-use UML diagramming tool for beginners?

Tags: software-recommendation, tools, diagram, uml

I'm trying to find a tool for creating UML diagrams for my work. Usability is a major criteria for me. I’m just starting out,many things to learn. Free would be great, but I would be glad to pay if the tool's worth it. Anyone have a good recommendation?

Answer (score 1):

I use [Papyrus](http://www.eclipse.org/papyrus/), an Eclipse extension. Usability is good enough if you are not up to complex stuff like profiles. But you get all the benefits of Eclipse integration, easy versioning, etc.

If you are up to code generation then Papyrus + [Acceleo](http://www.eclipse.org/acceleo) is the pretty much the only option around.